# issue with sending headers in post request to the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am making a post request to the API but the problem that i see is that the authtoken gets sent in request payload instead of request headers in network tab.

```
const fetchData =(id,authToken)=>
    axios
     .post(`${APIUrl}/${id}/math`,{
         headers:{
             ...getAuthHeaderWithContentType(authToken, "JSON")
         }
     })
     .then(resp => (resp && resp.data ? resp.data : null));
```

The headers should appear in request headers instead of request payload .

Comment: According to docs on gitthub, the method signature is `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])` - you are passing your headers as part of the data, they should be part of config instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you post a object what includes `headers` field as `data`.

`axios` official document said:
`axios.post(url, data, options)`

Just add `null` or `{}` as `data` if you do not have any data to post.

```
const fetchData = (id, authToken) =>
  axios
    .post(`${APIUrl}/${id}/math`, {}, {
      headers: {
        ...getAuthHeaderWithContentType(authToken, "JSON")
      }
    })
    .then(resp => (resp && resp.data ? resp.data : null));
```

But, I think use `POST` method to get data is not recommended.

Comment: Thnaks for your quick response .I didn't have enough time to look into docs and it really helped .